# How to fix 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous' error in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use an `if` statement to filter an Excel document. I need to specify the null values in the `valuer` column inside the `content` table (data frame), then drop the row holding the null value.

[image]

Comment: Follow the advice in the rest of the error message. Is a series with a mixture of true and false values overall true or false?

Comment: The error message is really very clear. What don't you understand about it? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: you may just need dropna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
content['valuer'].isnull()
```

will return a series of True / False values, True for a null value and False for every other value. If you want to check if any value of the row is null, use

```
any(content['valuer'].isnull())
```

If you want to check if all columns are null, use

```
all(content['valuer'].isnull())
```